# Where can I edit the blog page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, blog

I'm using the sharepoint 2010 blog site template for a few of our sites.

I'd like to add some default web parts and add some classes to a few extra elements so I can get the page styled properly but I can't find where the page layout for the blog pages is anywhere!

Note:  We're using Sharepoint Online so I don't have direct access to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

Site template and onet file:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\Blog

XSL File for blog itself:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL

Comment: Any idea how I'd get to that via SPD?  We're using Sharepoint Online so I don't have access to the file system.  Updated the question for clarity.

Comment: You create a new one, make your modifications in page (Add remove parts, subsites etc) then save as a template in 365 under site settings. Or make one from scratch/from an installation of 2010 and modify.

Comment: Ooo... good plan, will give that a try.